# Entity Framework 1:1 relationship Code First

Tags: ef-code-first

I'm struggling here. I've tried through data annotations and via the Fluent API and still not working correctly. Desperate for help now. Basically, I have two tables. A Company table and an Address Table. A company must have a head office address (which should live in the Address Table) and an Address must have a Company which is belongs too. I'm really struggling to set this up correctly.

I'll put the Code First Entities then show what I have already got.

```
[Table("Address")]
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public long AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string Address4 { get; set; }
    public string Address5 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RemovedDate { get; set; }
    public long? RemovedBy { get; set; }
}

[Table("Company")]
public class Company
{
    [Key ]
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public User LeadUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActiveSince { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ActiveTill { get; set; }
    public string VatRegistration { get; set; }
    public string LicenseKey { get; set; }
    public LicenseStatus LicenseStatus { get; set; }
    public bool CanAgreementBeExtended { get; set; }
    public string BillingEmail { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LicenseHistory> LicenseHistories { get; set; }
}

//Seeded data inserted as follows
 var testCompany = new Company
                          {
                              ActiveSince = DateTime.UtcNow,
                              Name = "Test Company",
                              LeadUser = adminUser,
                              DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                              DateUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                              BillingEmail = "admin@test.co.uk",
                              CanAgreementBeExtended = true,
                              LicenseStatus = LicenseStatus.PendingAgreement,
                              MobileNumber = "1234567890",
                              PhoneNumber = "1234567890",
                              VatRegistration = "1234567890"
                          };

        context.Companies.AddOrUpdate(u => u.Name, testCompany);

var testAddress = new Address
        {
            Address1 = "Test Ltd",
            Address2 = "1 Test Gardens",
            Address3 = "Test Heath",
            Address4 = string.Empty,
            Address5 = string.Empty,
            County = "Test",
            Town = "Test",
            Country = "United Kingdom",
            PostCode = "TE5 T11",
            Company = testCompany
        };

        context.Addresses.AddOrUpdate(u => new { u.AddressId }, testAddress);

        testCompany.Address = testAddress;

        context.Companies.AddOrUpdate(u => u.Name, testCompany);

//Fluent API set up as follows in the OnModelCreating
            modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
                    .HasRequired(ad => ad.Company)
                    .WithOptional(s => s.Address);
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? I've been playing round with different combinations for the past few days and it just doesn't work. I just keep getting errors, the latest error based on the code above is...

> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'AddressId'.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a true one to one in SQL Server (see [How do I create a real one-to-one relationship in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292355/how-do-i-create-a-real-one-to-one-relationship-in-sql-server)), but there is a workaround in EF where you make the primary key of the second entity also a foreign key:

```
// [Table("Company")] -- not needed unless different
public class Company
{
    // [Key ] -- will be key by convention
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Company")]
    public long AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

You can also do it with fluent code like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>() 
    .HasRequired(t => t.Address) 
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Company);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've seen this one before on my trawling of the internet for a solution but it doesn't quiet match what I'm after. As the Address table and the Company Table are used together and independently they each have an Identity set on their PK. The idea behind it is that a company can only have one Address (which is their head office) but a company may own multiple Addresses (hence the address has a Company column). This allows me to get the Companies Head Office address and also all Addresses owned by the company. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Ran out of characters :).....I've done this setup fine creating the DB tables myself but can't seem to map it to EF. :(

Comment: We have something similar where a person has many addresses, one of which is the primary address. We went many to many with 3 tables. Person, Address, PersonAddress. PersonAddress has navs to Person and Address as well as a IsPrimaryAddress flag. Person and Address each have a collection of PersonAddresses for nav purposes. Here is a good explanation: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/