# Entity Framework One To One Relationship WithRequiredPrinciple saving entities without dependent entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am implementing one to one relationship in entity framework using code first approach. Below are my models.

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public virtual Caption Caption { get; set; }

}
```

and this one

```
public class Caption
{

    public int CaptionId { get; set; }
    public string CaptionDesc { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

and in context I have used following code

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasRequired(c => c.Caption).WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.Course);
```

while reading this article here, [One to One Relationship Example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), They said that when let's say you are saving course entity without caption so exception will be thrown and entity framework won't let you store the entity. But When I did, I didn't got any exception. I can store both entities without any dependency. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I am using entity framework 6

Edit: The tables looks as following. [image]

Comment: You haven't put any `Primary Keys` or `Foreign Keys` on either table showing their constraints. How do the tables look in `SQL Server SSMS`?

Comment: He doesn't need to. Courseid and CaptionId follow convention so EF is smart enough to tell.

Comment: That's what I thought, but if he's inserting rows without `Caption`, then shouldn't he explicitly enforce the relationships with `Key` and `Foreign Key`?

Comment: Technically you can't do 1:1 in SQL Server. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292355/how-do-i-create-a-real-one-to-one-relationship-in-sql-server). The usual approach is described in your link: Add CourseId (and remove CaptionId) to the Caption table and make CourseId BOTH the primary key and foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

1:1 relationships in entity framework are only supported when the tables share a primary key. Check out this article for help understanding: http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-one-to-one-mapping/