# ASP .NET MVC - Fails Updating One-to-One Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am building a web application using ASP .NET MVC5 and EF6.
I have an one-to-one relationship defined as follows:

```
public class Client 
{
  public int ClientId { get; set; }  
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address 
{
  [ForeignKey("Client")]
  public int AddressId { get; set; }  
  [Required]
  public string StreetName { get; set; }

  public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Where Address is the dependent end.
After enabling Migrations and updating the database, the two tables are created, in which, **the Address table contains a ClientId column**, as a result of the Foreign Key.

I then proceeded to generate the Controllers and Views for these classes.

For the Address, I'm trying to modify the Create/Edit methods and views to be able to add a new address and associate it to an existing Client, which is exactly what is done in this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

My AddressController was customized exactly as the tutorial suggests as well as the respective views. But upon accessing the Create page while running the web app, I am able to write a street name and choose from a drop down list a name for the client (which is what I want, display the client name and not the Id).

When hitting the create button, I get the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Addresses_dbo.Clients_AddressId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "myDb", table "dbo.Clients", column 'ClientId'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

This leads me to believe that the Foreign Key ClientId is not being updated as it was supposed to be by selecting a name in the drop down list. I tried adding new clients without addresses associated to them but even by selecting a client without an associated address the error persists.

I also know that, ideally, the drop down list should actually only show the clients without any address associated to them but I don't know how to accomplish this.

Because I followed every step of the mentioned tutorial, I don't really know what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be extremely appreciated! If there is a need to post more code, I will do it, just didn't do it in order to shorten this already long post.

### Update Code

**AddressesController.cs**

```
public class AddressesController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Addresses
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var addresses = db.Addresses.Include(m => m.Client);
            return View(addresses.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Addresses/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Address address = db.Addresses.Find(id);
            if (address == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(address);
        }

    // GET: Address/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            PopulateClientsDropDownList(); 
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Addresses/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AddressId,StreetName,ClientId")] Address address)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    db.Addresses.Add(addresses);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (DataException dex)
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
                ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(dex);
            }
            PopulateClientsDropDownList(address.ClientId);
        return View(address);
        }

    // GET: Addresses/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

        Address address = db.Address.Find(id);
            if (address == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            PopulateClientsDropDownList(address.ClientId); 

            return View(address);
        }

        // POST: Addresses/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditPost(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var addressToUpdate = db.Addresses.Find(id);
            if (TryUpdateModel(addressToUpdate, "",
                new string[] { "StreetName", "ClientId" }))
            {
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (RetryLimitExceededException dex)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
                    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(dex);
                }
            }
            PopulateAddressesDropDownList(addressToUpdate.ClientId);
            return View(addressToUpdate);
        }

    private void PopulateClientsDropDownList(object selectedClient = null)
        {
            var clientsQuery = from d in db.Clients
                               orderby d.Name
                               select d;
            ViewBag.ClientId = new SelectList(clientsQuery, "ClientId", "Name", selectedClient);
        }
}
```

**Create.cshtml**
(Shortened)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Addresses</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @*<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressId, "AddressId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("AddressId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>*@

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ClientId">Client Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10"> 
                @Html.DropDownList("ClientId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: It may be that the correct, or any, `ClientID` is not being added to the new address.Without seeing the update code it's hard to know.

Comment: Is not good idea to add the foreign key with attributes. maybe you can use fluent Api.

Comment: @PeterSmith which code do you need exactly? Should I only post the controller's code or also the Create's view?

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the new address to the database and therefore add the `ClientID`

Comment: @PeterSmith just updated my question with the rest of the code.

Comment: You need to trace your code for the `ActionResult Create` and check to see what values are coming back. I suspect that the problem is in the returned values.

Comment: Could be an issue where AddressId is both PK and required FK which is [technically impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292355/how-do-i-create-a-real-one-to-one-relationship-in-sql-server/10292449) in SQL Server. Try one of the workarounds like [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx). When you get further along I would consider using viewmodels that hold everything rather than ViewBag and bind statements.

Comment: @SteveGreene just checked the workarounds you mentioned but I believe that was exactly what I did, by using Data Annotations. And I'm getting really confused because according to that site: **"A one-to-zero-or-one relationship happens when a primary key of one table becomes PK & FK in another table in a relational database such as SQL Server.** So, doesn't this contradict what you are saying about AddressId being both PK and FK?

Comment: @Sfmar why do you have Foreign key annotation on PK AddressId? Change your model, add **Id** property in Address class that will be your PK. Or try with nullable FK, add **int?** with AddressId property. Although, that's not the way you should create your models. Always have separate primary key and foreign key properties.

Comment: @SushiDynamite I followed the guidelines provided by Entity Framework on how to configure one-to-zero-or-one relationship using data annotation attributes. If you check this url [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), this is exactly what they do.

Comment: @Sfmar you forgot **virtual** keyword as I can see from your code and one from link.

Comment: @SushiDynamite **virtual** only enables lazy loading, which should not have impact on the problem I'm having. But anyway, I also tried with **virtual** and results are the same, unfortunately.

Comment: @Sfmar sry, you are right about virtual keyword, totally forgot that one :)   edit: did you try mapping tables using Fluent API?