# How to create a one-to-one relationship for creating a "status" database table for another table that needs to keep record of those statuses

Tags: sql, jpa, one-to-one, ebean

I have a database table: Admin(id, name, status_id) fields and another AdminStatus(id, code, description). I initially though of creating a one-to-one relationship by creating a unique constraint on status_code field in the Admin table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE admin_status
( id INT NOT NULL,
  code INT NOT NULL,
  description varchar2(10) NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT  admin_status_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE admin_status
( id INT NOT NULL,
  code INT NOT NULL,
  description varchar2(10) NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT  admin_status_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

JPA Mappings (I'm using EBean ORM btw):

```
@Entity
public class admin extends Model {

    private String name;
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "admin", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private AdminStatus status;
```

My question is different from the one below, in my opinion base on the fact that any number Admins can be either Active - 0 or Inactive - ), hence can't be set as a unique constraint:

[How to Create a real one-to-one relationship in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292355/how-to-create-a-real-one-to-one-relationship-in-sql-server)

How should I implement this properly so that the relationship are mapped correctly and optimally in JPA or EBean?

Comment: Can one AdminStatus apply to many Admins but an Admin can have only one AdminStatus?

Comment: @Honeyboy Wilson yes, that was my thinking mostly just that I wasn't sure if I was right to think that way but practically it makes sense

Comment: That's the classic definition of a one-to-many relationship, not a one-to-one relationship.