# Foreign-Key Reference on View

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there any possibility to reference to a field of a view to be sure about integrity?

Pseudocode example:

```
CREATE VIEW V_ONE AS SELECT .....
CREATE TABLE TWO ( ID INT REFERENCES V_ONE ( field ))
```

I **don't** want to `CREATE TABLE T_ONE` instead of `V_ONE` first to be able to reference `T_ONE`.

@edit:

View `V_ONE` collects data from multiple tables of an erp-system an preprocesses them. Table `TWO` extends `V_ONE` with some additional data, which should not be included into `V_ONE`. There must not be an entry in table `TWO` for every  entry in `V_ONE`, but I want to be sure there's no entry in table `TWO` for which no base-data can be found in `V_ONE`.

Comment: A view is just a query, there is no data there to validate, unless you're talking about the underlying table(s). Can you explain why the constraint can't be against whatever table is behind the view?

Comment: Please post the select for the view and the name of the field you want to reference.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The view generates an `ID` per row which is used for all further processing of its data and it would be nice to check against this `ID`. The view itself is treated as a kind of data-interface between ERP-tables and ERP-AddOn.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer : no. Sql Server doesn't allow to use a Foreign Key on a view.

You could put the Foreign Key constraint on "one of the table" referenced in the view, but without context... Hard to give a convenient answer.

Edit : well, what about a [check constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) on Two, with a query on v_one ?

But you'll have to find a way to manage deletion (and updates) on "source tables" of v_one.

You could use (untested) an [INSTEAD OF DELETE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191208%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (and [INSTEAD OF UPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188601%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) if needed) trigger on your view (V_ONE) with the check constraint on your table (TWO).

Comment: longer answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928355/tsql-foreign-keys-on-views

Comment: @mcalex: I know about the linked question. But it does not exactly cover my question. He asked for asuring data integrity via inserting data into the view. I instead want to reference from a table to a view!

Comment: what about using a trigger(s) to implement the constraint ?

Comment: @tschmit007 Thought about the same. Instead of insert trigger on Table TWO which checks for existing PK in V_ONE.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Trigger on ERP tables won't work. Ever worked with DynamicsAX? ;)

Comment: @Nico  Didn't even ever hear the name ;) Well, you could maybe add a trigger on your view (// with check constraint), but I never tried it : see http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/SQLServer/0440__Trigger/CREATEINSTEADOFDELETETRIGGERONaview.htm (see also edited post)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar result with a check constraint rather than a Foreign key:

```
-- CREATE VIEW THAT RETURNS DUMMY DATA
CREATE VIEW V_ONE
AS
SELECT  Field
FROM    (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) T (Field);
GO

-- CREATE FUNCTION THAT VALIDATES CRITERIA
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckFunction (@ID INT)
RETURNS BIT AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM V_ONE WHERE Field = @ID)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1;
    END

    RETURN 0;

END
GO
-- CREATE TABLE THAT REFERENCES VIEW
CREATE TABLE T_TWO (ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CHK_T_TWO_ID CHECK (dbo.CheckFunction(ID) = 1));

-- TRY INSERTING A VALUE NOT RETURNED BY V_ONE
INSERT T_TWO VALUES (4);
```

You will probably need to implement triggers to handle deletes/updates to the source of V_One, You should probably add a foreign key to the source too.