# How to validate TimeZone Name (FK?) in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timezone

SQL Server 2016 has a view `sys.time_zone_info`. In my table I store the Time Zone Name (from that view). Now, I cannot (apparently) simply define a FK from my table's column to that view:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [TimeZone_Name_FK] 
   FOREIGN KEY ([TimeZone_Name]) REFERENCES sys.time_zone_info([Name])
```

I would like to ensure that the data in my table is validated against that view. How would you suggest I handle this? A trigger seems to be overkill.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447122/can-i-have-a-foreign-key-referencing-a-column-in-a-view-in-sql-server

Comment: In order for a foreign key to work, the column you reference in the *parent table* must be either the **primary key** of that table, or it has to be part of a **unique constraint** on that table. Is either of this the case with `Name` in  `sys.time_zone_info` ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL foreign keys on views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928355/tsql-foreign-keys-on-views)

Comment: Here is what I did. This is not perfect as there is a performance hit, but there are not that many lines in the table.
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK ([dbo].[Is_TimeZone_FN]([TimeZone_Name]) <> 0)
... using a simple function that checks the TimeZone.  Is there a better way? Any comments?
...